# "Failed to open a session for the virtual machine ubuntu 20.04"

Tags: virtualbox

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine ubuntu 20.04.
>
> The native API dll was not found (C:\Windows\system32\WinHvPlatform.dll) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
>
> VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).
>
> Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
> Component: ConsoleWrap
> Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Comment: "VT-x is disabled in the BIOS " is not an Ubuntu issue. Check your BIOS for compatibility for Virtual machines.

Answer (score 1):

> The native API dll was not found
> (C:\Windows\system32\WinHvPlatform.dll) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).

This is not ubuntu's issue. Ask Windows support.